# How to prevent receiving the same random data from the list in python

Tags: python, list, random

I want to check that the random cards from the list are not the same card. How can I do that? Can you help me?
Thanks.

```
import random
vals = ['2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', 'J', 'Q', 'K', 'A']
suits = ['C', 'D', 'H', 'S']
name = []
playercount=int(input("Please Enter Number of Player = "))

if  2 <= playercount <= 5:
    for i in range(playercount):
        username=str(input("Please Enter Player Name: "))
        if not username:
            name.append("Player {}".format(i+1))
            name.append(random.choices(vals))
            name.append(random.choices(suits))    
        else:   
            name.append(username)
            name.append(random.choices(vals))
            name.append(random.choices(suits))
    print("Players, Vals and Suits on the Desk ")
    for x in range(len(name)):
        print (name[x])
else:
    print("Try Again")
```

Comment: You mean you want to `shuffle` them?

Comment: I think you want 'without replacement' i.e you won't get the same card twice. Use np.random.choice(vals, replace=False)

Comment: i said Randomly select one card from the deck (The selected cards cannot be selected again)

Comment: with `len(set(name)) == len(name)` you can check if duplicates are present in the list

Comment: @FevzicanOzgen does my answer answer your question? If not please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

One strategy would be to create a list that stores the cards in a deck and to randomly draw cards from that list. Each time a card is drawn, that card is removed from that list so that when you draw more cards randomly from that list, you never get the same card more than once.

```
not_in_hand = [x + y for x in vals for y in suits]
```

In a program, this might look like

```
import random

rank = ['2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', 'J', 'Q', 'K', 'A']
suit = ['C', 'D', 'H', 'S']

# list of all possible cards
not_in_hand = [x + y for x in rank for y in suit]

# dictionary whereby a key is a player name (e.g. 'Bonnie') and a value is
# a card (e.g. '2C')
hands = {}

while True:
    try:
        playercount = int(input("Number of Players: "))
    except ValueError:
        print("Please enter an integer in [2,5]!")
        continue

    if 2 <= playercount <= 5:
        break
    else:
        print("Player count must be in [2, 5].")


for i in range(playercount):
    username = input("Enter Player Name: ")
    # if nothing entered, give default name
    if not username:
        username = f"Player {i + 1}"

    # randomly draw a card
    index = random.randint(0, len(not_in_hand) - 1)
    card = not_in_hand.pop(index)

    # record the card that the player has drawn
    hands[username] = card

print(hands)
```

Output:

```
Number of Players: jack
Please enter an integer in [2,5]!
Number of Players: 1
Player count must be in [2, 5].
Number of Players: 3
Enter Player Name: Bonnie
Enter Player Name: Clyde
Enter Player Name: 
{'Bonnie': 'AH', 'Clyde': 'KD', 'Player 3': '7S'}
```

I hope that this helps. Please let me know if there are any questions.